Кириллица в jasper report
Есть код, отправляющий jasper отчет на почту
FORM notificationNewComment
    OBJECTS c = Comment
    PROPERTIES (c) ticketId, ticketSubject, text, employeeName
;

notifyEmployee(Comment c, Employee e) {
    MESSAGE 'notify new comment: ' + name(e) LOG NOWAIT;
    LOCAL bodyFile = FILE ();
    PRINT notificationNewComment OBJECTS c = c HTML TO bodyFile;
    EMAIL
        SUBJECT 'TICKETID: [' + id(ticket(c)) + '] Новый комментарий к заявке'
        TO address(defaultEmail(e))
        BODY bodyFile()
    NOWAIT
    ;
}

После переноса в production (находится в докере), перестала отображаться кириллица.
Выглядит вот так:

Где-то в настройках нужно проставить кодировку?
Если сравнивать тело писем, то после переноса добавился шрифт в CSS

и ссылка на него
<link class=3D"jrWebFont" rel=3D"stylesheet" href=3D"lsf1652873724445115566=
8.html_files/DejaVu Sans_-en_US">

UPD1:
Только что заметил, в письме все отображается верно. Просто все символы заменены на знак вопроса. Видимо где-то раньше.
Нормальное письмо:
<div style=3D"padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"><span style=3D"font-fami=
ly: DejaVu Sans; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 20px; line-height: 1; *line-hei=
ght: normal; font-weight: bold;">=D0=90=D0=9A=D0=A0: =D0=97=D0=90=D0=AF=D0=
=92=D0=9A=D0=98</span></div></td>

Кривое письмо:
<div style=3D"padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"><span style=3D"font-fami=
ly: 'DejaVu Sans_-en_US', 'DejaVu Sans'; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 20px; l=
ine-height: 1; *line-height: normal; font-weight: bold;">=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=
=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD: =EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=
=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD</s=
pan></div></td>

UPD2:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3
DOCKER: Docker version 25.0.1, build 29cf629
JAVA: openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14
LSFUSION: 6.0-beta0 (292)
services:
  server:
    container_name: server
    image: lsfusion/server:6.0-beta0
    volumes:
      - ./lsfusion:/lsfusion
    networks:
      - app
    environment:
      - LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
      - TZ=Europe/Moscow
      - DB_PASSWORD=***
      - DB_SERVER=***
      - DB_USER=***
      - DB_NAME=***
#      - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx4000m
    restart: unless-stopped
  client:
    container_name: client
    image: lsfusion/client:6.0-beta0
#    ports:
#      - 8080
    depends_on:
      - server
    volumes:
      - ./conf:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina
    networks:
      - nginx
      - app
    environment:
      - LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
      - SERVER_HOST=server
#      - SERVER_PORT=7652
#      - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx4000m
    restart: unless-stopped
networks:
  nginx:
    external: true
  app:
    external: true


А изначально у вас в jrxml fontName прописан? Дело, судя по всему не в кодировке, а в шрифте.

Да, шрифт задан
   <textField>
    <reportElement stretchType="ElementGroupHeight" x="200" y="0" width="560" height="40" uuid="330b1c45-21b8-4309-983e-e78d4e2e3265"/>
    <box padding="5"/>
    <textElement>
     <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="20"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ticketId(c)}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>



А в заголовке письма, там где "Новый комментарий к заявке" правильно отображается ?
И если сделать вместо open(bodyFile()) - там что будет в html ?
Еще можно попробовать передать файл не в BODY, а в ATTACH и посмотреть, что там будет с кодировкой.
Это все нужно, чтобы понять, где символы преобразовываются неправильно.

Еще можете попробовать вот такой скрипт в Интерпретаторе :
FORM testForm
PROPERTIES myProp = 'Привет!!!'
;
run {
LOCAL bodyFile = FILE ();
PRINT testForm HTML TO bodyFile;
EMAIL
SUBJECT 'Новый комментарий к заявке'
TO 'test@gmail.com'
BODY bodyFile() ;
}
Там будет потеря кодировки или нет ?


В заголовке отображается правильно
через open(bodyFile()) открывается нормально
через ATTACH тоже нормально
Скрипт в интерпретаторе теряет кодировку


Еще тогда пригодятся версия ОС, Java и lsFusion. Еще можно попробовать в скрипте вместо BODY bodyFile() попробовать отправить строку вроде BODY 'Привет' и посмотреть потеряется ли кодировка.

Если отправить 'Привет' без bodyFile(), то с кодировкой все нормально. Информацию по версиям добавил в вопрос. Я запускаю в докере, приложил docker-compose.

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.

Вероятнее всего, неправильно выставлена кодировка для виртуальной машины Java. На данный момент, lsFusion не полностью поддерживает все кодировки отличные от UTF-8.
Чтобы выставить кодировку UTF-8 для сервера приложений нужно добавить следующую строку в параметры запуска сервера :
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8

При использовании стандартного инсталлятора параметры запуска находятся в файле /etc/lsfusion6-server/conf/lsfusion.conf - строка FUSION_OPTS=.

В самых последних сборках уже вроде исправили эту проблему с кодировками, и все должно быть хорошо независимо от установленной кодировки сервера приложений (то есть даже если она не UTF8).

Да, это работает. В случае с докером нужно вносить правки внутри контейнера в entrypoint.sh
